# WPF. Как сослаться на переменную из другого класса?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется переменная `SelfPath` с изменяющимся значением. При нажатии на кнопку на главном окне всплывает вторичное окно `CreateFileWindow`, в текстбоксе которого необходимо отобразить значение `SelfPath`. Возможно, это что-то банальное, но я новичок в c#, как я могу сослаться на эту переменную?

```
namespace CommandExecutor
{
    public partial class CreateFileWindow : Window
    {
        public string ViewModel { get; set; }
        public CreateFileWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DragMove();
        }
        private void btnX_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        private void btnCreateFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileDirTextBox.Text = "MainWindow.SelfPath ?";//здесь нужна переменная
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Process CmdProcess = new Process();
        bool isWindowToggled = false;
        public string SelfPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;//переменная
```

Comment: Объявить ее статической.

Comment: `public string ViewModel { get; set; }` - если уж начали использовать MVVM, то учитесь его использовать до конца. Ну а так, делайте приватное свойство в классе `CreateFileWindow` и переопределяйте конструктор на нечто такое `public CreateFileWindow(MainWindow wind) { свойство = wind; }`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я дал ответ, но это могли сделать и вы, в нем букв примерно столько же, сколько в вашем первом комментарии.

Comment: @aepot Я вам сказал свое мнение, я против подобных вопросов на SO и если будет возможность, то я всеми руками буду за их удаление. На сколько я знаю вопросы без ответов, а еще если и заминусованные со временем удаляются с SO. Это тоже повод для меня не давать ответ. Вы можете глянуть мои ответы и увидите, что большинство из них - это развернутый на несколько сотен слов ответы, с подробнейшим примером и описанием. А ответы, которые сейчас дали вы я буду кидать в комментарии, ибо бесполезны и всего в пару строк. Не согласны - давайте ответы сами, но не учите других как им поступать, пожалуйста!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если на ответе нет положительных голосов, то вопрос тоже будет удалён автоматикой)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модифицируйте конструктор дочернего окна и добавьте поле, хранящее ссылку на основное окно.

```csharp
private MainWindow _main;

public CreateFileWindow(MainWindow main)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _main = main;
}
```

Используйте вот так

```csharp
FileDirTextBox.Text = _main.SelfPath;
```

Создавайте дочернее окно вот так

```csharp
new CreateFileWindow(this);
```